# Simple Requirejs script not returning contained function

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I just can't understand what I did Wrong

```
require(['jquery'],
    function($){
        function main() {
            console.log("test");
        }
    return main;
});
```

Comment: If you want to return a value that is going to be used somewhere else you should be using `define`, not `require`. It is impossible to return anything meaningful with `require`. The return value will be swallowed and not available anywhere else.

Comment: @Louis the function is page specific, also I get this Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module which I just can't get considering no other

Answer (score -1):

just try this one, it works fine for me by removing the parentheses that is surrounding the function

```
require['jquery'],
function($){
    function main() {
        console.log("test");
    }
return main;
};
```

Comment: not sure what you are testing in but that doesn't seem to work for me atleast